# RHEL - can't sudo from script

Tags: linux, rhel

I have a script where I'm trying to change user (from root) on boot. In /etc/rc.d/rc.local, I've changed it to cd into the script dir and execute it. It all works except for when it tries to execute:

```
sudo -u newuser ./myscript.sh
```

I get an error message:

```
sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

So I went and looked in my /etc/sudoers file, and it is already set to !requiretty, which should turn that off. I have also tried alternatives such as gksudo, but apparently RHEL 6.5 only supports basic sudo.

I know the script works because I can execute it myself from terminal, it's just when I try and execute it from a boot script.

Comment: you shouldn't need to use sudo when you're already root, use `su`. Also, this is probably off topic on SO, should go to superuser.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. And I'll take it to superuser next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed:

```
sudo -u newuser ./myscript.sh
```

To:

```
/bin/su -c ./myscript.sh newuser
```

And it seems to work. I guess because sudo is normally there to elevate your privileges but since it starts as root I don't really need it and can use su instead. Will try this out in various places to make sure it works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
su -u newuser -c ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: It will be more helpful if you can add one or two liner description for this answer.

Comment: Su--Switch user (-u for username -c for Commad ) ./ means run the script from current directory

Comment: su sometimes does not recognize -u option, instead you have to do like this: `su -c "./myscript.sh" - newuser`